# Why Android studio keeps doing Gradle sync when launching the debugger?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Why, if I do a gradle sync and then I launch a debug session, Android Studio starts another gradle sync? Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because it rebuilds the app. then attach the debugger to the application.

in case your app is already running and you didn't change the code you can use "Attach debugger to Android process" as shown in the picture:

[image]